# Why is xmlrpc not working after I changed my Wordpress theme and domain?

Tags: python, wordpress

I have been successfully been uploading to my Wordpress site using the wordpress_xmlrpc package in Python.

```
client = Client('https://website.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username',
                'password')
```

However, after installing a new theme (Newspaper) and changing my domain from '.wordpress.com' to '.uk', I now receive the following errors...

If I use 'https://website.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php':

wordpress_xmlrpc.exceptions.ServerConnectionError: <ProtocolError for website.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php: 301 Moved Permanently>

If I use 'https://website.uk/xmlrpc.php':

xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32601: 'server error. requested method mt.supportedMethods does not exist.'>